# Using session wrapper for accessing session data

Tags: c#, .net, session

When users log in to our website, we store some information in a session to retrieve it across the site. We created a few wrappers to help with data retrieval/storage to lessen duplication of code.

I'm trying to redesign it as I don't like how the UserModel is written. I believe it's dangerous with the static properties, but so far it's been working.

However...

While we haven't noticed any issues, recently someone use something very similar to our code (slightly modified) for another project and had about 20+ people log in at the same time. Some users saw other user's information instead of their own. This brought a huge concern on the original code (below) and would like to get any feedback on how to make it "better" or avoid the same issue they ran into (if it even will happen).

I searched/read around Google/Stack Overflow about the possible issue being at our `static` method wrappers.

**UserModel.cs**

```
public class User {
    private const Boolean UseSessionAsDataStore = true;

    protected const String kUserId = "UserId";
    protected const String kUserName = "UserName";
    protected const String kUserEmail = "UserEmail";

    public static Int32 UserId {
        get { return GetInt32Value(kUserId); }
        set { SaveValue(kUserId, value.ToString()); }
    }

    public static String UserName {
        get { return GetStringValue(kUserName); }
        set { SaveValue(kUserName, value); }
    }

    public static String UserEmail {
        get { return GetStringValue(kUserEmail); }
        set { SaveValue(kUserEmail, value); }
    }

    protected static void SaveValue(String key, String value) {
        UseSessionAsDataStore ?
        SessionHelper.SaveSessionValue(key, value) :
        CookieHelper.SaveCookieValue(key, value);
    }

    protected static void GetStringValue(String key) {
        UseSessionAsDataStore ? SessionHelper.GetSessionStringValue(key) : CookieHelper.GetCookieStringValue(key);
    }

    protected static void GetInt32Value(String key) {
        UseSessionAsDataStore ? SessionHelper.GetSessionInt32Value(key) : CookieHelper.GetCookieInt32Value(key);
    }
}
```

**UserLoginModel.cs**

```
public class UserLoginModel {
    AssignUser (Int32 userId, String userName, String userEmail) {
        UserModel.UserId = userId;
        UserModel.UserName = userName;
        UserModel.UserEmail = userEmail;
    }
}
```

**SessionHelper.cs**

(won't provide CookieModel.cs as it's not the issue in question)

```
public class SessionHelper {
    public static void SaveSessionValue(String key, String value) {
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(key, value);
    }

    public static String GetSessionStringValue(String key) {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session == null || HttpContext.Current.Session[key] == null) { return null; }
        return HttpContext.Current.Session[key] != null ? HttpContext.Current.Session[key].ToString() : String.Empty;
    }

    public static Int32 GetSessionInt32Value(String key) {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session == null || HttpContext.Current.Session[key] == null) { return 0; }
        Int32 value;
        Int32.TryParse(HttpContext.Current.Session[key].ToString(), out value);
        return value;
    }
}
```

**LoginPage**

```
/* try to log in user and return user data */
...
if (loginSuccessful) {
    UserLoginModel.AssignUser(userId, userName, userEmail);
}
...
```

**MainPage**

```
<html>
    <body>
        Hello <%=UserModel.UserName %>!
    </body>
</html>
...
```

I have a feeling that this code has the potential to share session data between 2 users, although we have yet to realize it, even with about 5 simultaneous logins.

Comment: @Jamal, thanks for the edit, but now the Main Page section doesn't show the greater-than and less-than signs.

Comment: There aren't any in the post now.  Even when I added some myself, I did see them show up.

Comment: @Jamal This is what OP refers to : http://imgur.com/7slL2fK

Comment: @RoLYroLLs You may want to take a look to this : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/917072

Comment: @Xiaoy312, thanks we do use this in several pages on our site which have dynamic data. I'll check the other site they created to see if they have this or not, as I forgot this can be an issue.

Comment: @Xiaoy312, you are correct sir! They were not commenting out the outputCache on their dynamic pages. We did a few tests to confirm this was the issue. I'm not saying it is/was the ONLY issue, but that's a start. Could you comment on the rest of the code? Does it seem legit or should I change something around?

Comment: Why are all the properties `static`?

Comment: @RubberDuck not sure, it was like this before I got here.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not use Hungarian notation for constants, keep it in PascalCase. If you like to differentiate the names from the properties you can name in form of `{PropertyName}Key`, like `UserIdKey`.
2. Do prefer .net aliases over the full type name, like `Int32` -> `int`, `String` -> `string`.
3. Avoid repetition of word, like `User.UserId` and `SessionHelper.GetSession...`. Unless you are worried about mixed up with the foreign key in your DTO, but it is not the case here.
4. `UserModel` (if it is `User`, that is fine)(you weren't really consistent with the code) should be renamed to `CurrentUser` :

   ```
   // which one makes more sense ?
   UserModel.Name = userName;
   CurrentUser.Name = userName;
   ```
5. `HttpContext.Current.Session` shows up quite frequently in `SessionHelper`, you could use a property to shorten it :

   ```
   private static HttpSessionState CurrentSession
   {
       get { return HttpContext.Current.Session; }
   }
   ```

---

The `SessionHelper` class :

```
public class SessionHelper
{
    private static HttpSessionState Session
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Session; }
    }

    public void SaveValue(string key, string value)
    {
        Session.Add(key, value);
    }
    public static string GetStringValue(string key)
    {
        if (Session == null || Session[key] == null)
            return null;

        return HttpContext.Current.Session[key].ToString();
    }
    public static int GetIntValue(string key)
    {
        if (Session == null || Session[key] == null)
            return 0;

        int result;
        return int.TryParse(Session[key].ToString(), out result) ? result : 0;
    }
}
```

If you can get your hand on C# 6, consider this version :

```
public class SessionHelper_c6
{
    private static HttpSessionState Session => HttpContext.Current.Session;

    public void SaveValue(string key, string value)
    {
        Session.Add(key, value);
    }
    public static string GetStringValue(string key)
    {
        return Session?[key]?.ToString() ?? null;
    }
    public static int GetIntValue(string key)
    {
        var value = Session?[key]?.ToString() ?? null;
        int result;
        return value != null && int.TryParse(value, out result) ? result : 0;
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Thanks! I use ReSharper and the defaults for constant are that way and we never changed it and were ok with it. I agree with #3 as I do that with my personal projects and will be using this method when I change the User model where I work. for #2 I actually do not like using the alias, but I guess its just a preference everyone has. Lastly, besides the `outputCache` do you see any issues with the `session` and possible return of someone else's session because of the `static` `GET` methods?

Comment: Also, if you don't mind, would you be able to give some insight into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37197086/asp-net-c-sharp-object-persists-after-saving-to-session-once?noredirect=1#comment61926743_37197086 Thanks!

Comment: @RoLYroLLs I left an answer on your question. Almost missed your comment, had this answer not been upvoted today. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

A public static property or a public static field is equivalent to a global variable.

What you can do is, create a security token at logon and store it in a session or cookie. Then, create a `Sessions` class with a static `Dictionary` and `SaveUser` and `RestoreUser` static methods. In `SaveUser`, you add the `UserModel` instance to the dictionary using the security token as the key; in `RestoreUser`, you retrieve the `UserModel` instance, again using the security token as the key.

Once you have done this, you can add additional features, such as timestamping the user model so that it expires after a set time.

Comment: Thanks! I will look ingot this. Could you provide some sample code to get me started?